# IDN conversion failed

Tags: laravel, guzzle

I built a system with laravel-admin and guzzle. I send api requests to Shopify with Guzzle and everything works fine on my local environment. However, when I try to create a product in production , it gives me this error.

> IDN conversion failed

I looked into it on Google, and it seems Guzzle is giving me this error because I get the error only when I try to create the kinds of products that I sync with Shopify with guzzle.

There is not much information about the error on Google, and I am lost as to why it is happening. Has anyone experienced the same issue?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please add PHP and Guzzle versions to the question? I'm one of the authors of this feature, and (unfortunately) there were some issues related in specific cases. But to say something I need more details.

Generally, try to upgrade to the latest version. Things probably should be fine with [the latest Guzzle 6.5.2](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/releases/tag/6.5.2).

Comment: I figured out why it was happening, it was because my env variables were null. It was not caused by Guzzle!

Answer (score 0):

I've also suddenly started running into this issue. I have PHP version 7.2.30 running on the server and cURL version 7.19.7.

It worked fine yesterday, and wasn't working properly this morning. Nothing has changed, other than I upgraded Laravel and all dependencies. However, I think the particular code in the Guzzle Utils.php file where this error is being triggered has been around for quite a while. I tried downgrading Laravel to versions from much earlier this year, and Guzzle stayed the same.

We recently updated our web server, but that didn't make a difference to the PHP version nor should it have affected configuration.

This error I'm getting right now is baffling and I have no idea how to troubleshoot it.

**EDIT:** I found a simple work around for this problem through server configuration. After digging through the codebase in Laravel I noticed that Symfony provides polyfils if the intl extension is not installed. As such, I just disabled the intl extension on the server, which caused it to use the polyfils, which resolved the problem for me.

I checked first to see what version of ICU the intl was using, and it was an older version and hence the reason I got the errors.

So if you are running Laravel or anything else Symfony based and are having this problem, this could be a simple solution if you can't upgrade to a newer version of PHP for whatever reason. We are running a Plesk-based server, so we are dependent on them providing PHP and all the various extensions and we can't control their upgrade timing.

If you don't have that problem, then your other option would be to upgrade your PHP yourself and ensure the intl extension is up to date and compiled against a more current version of ICU.

Comment: This should really be a comment as it doesn't offer a solution to the OP. If you don't have the rep to comment then answer questions to get upvotes and accepts in order to gain some, alternatively ask your own questions.

Comment: He can't comment since he is a new member :)